# Unexpected argument due to sqlite3/database file

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to do Harvard's CS50 problem set.  This is my code so far:

```py
import sys
import sqlite3
import csv

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Error!")
    sys.exit(1)

db = sqlite3.connect("students.db")

with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as csvfile:
    database = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))

    for row in database:
        name = row["name"].split()

        if len(name) == 3:
            db.execute("INSERT INTO students (first, middle, last, house, birth) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                       name[0], name[1], name[2], row["house"], row["birth"])

        elif len(name) == 2:
            db.execute("INSERT INTO students (first, last, house, birth) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)",
                       name[0], name[1], row["house"], row["birth"])
```

However, when I tried to run it, the compiler said there are 'unexpected arguments' in these lines:

```
name[0], name[1], name[2], row["house"], row["birth"])

name[0], name[1], row["house"], row["birth"])
```

What could be the problem and what should I do?

Comment: The arguments to the query have to be given as one tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.execute` expects the the 2nd argument to be sequence or mapping. (You can simply wrap the parameter values with a parenthesis to make a tuple and it should work okay)

```py
if len(name) == 3:
      db.execute("INSERT INTO students (first, middle, last, house, birth) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                      (name[0], name[1], name[2], row["house"], row["birth"]))

elif len(name) == 2:
      db.execute("INSERT INTO students (first, last, house, birth) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)",
                       (name[0], name[1], row["house"], row["birth"]))
```